# Is there a cross platform .NET equivalent to Win32.SetEvent(int)?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, cross-platform

Is there a cross platform .NET equivalent to Win32 `SetEvent(int)`?

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetEvent(IntPtr hEvent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question without any context. The class `ManualResetEvent` ([Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[Mono](https://github.com/mosa/Mono-Class-Libraries/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/ManualResetEvent.cs)) should be present in .NET and Mono. It should handle all your basic needs with event signalling.

There are a lot of more sophisticated classes in [System.Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that may be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and use the `Set` and `Reset` methods to control its signaled state.